Placing a button on the status bar
I want to place a invisible button behind the display cutout on the status bar. I don't want to display a notification to the user like other codes but an invisible button on the status bar.I have added code to detect the size and the position of the display cutout but I'm unable to place a button on the status bar that is placed right behind the display cutout. I want to make the user to tap the camera notch and there should be a invisible button behind the camera notch.
I have used below code. In this the button is visible on the status bar but it's not clickable.
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class ButtonOverlayService extends Service {
    
        private WindowManager windowManager;
        private Button overlayButton;
    
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
    
            // Create WindowManager and set LayoutParams for the overlay button
            windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ?
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY :
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            );
    
            // Set gravity to the top of the screen including the status bar
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            params.x = 0;
            params.y = 0;
    
            // Inflate the overlay button layout
            overlayButton = new Button(this);
            overlayButton.setText("Button");
            overlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Handle button click
                    Toast.makeText(ButtonOverlayService.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    
            // Add the button to the window manager
            windowManager.addView(overlayButton, params);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (overlayButton != null) {
                windowManager.removeView(overlayButton);
            }
        }
    }

